# Reaper + Bias FX 2 + ASIO4ALL: Reaper shows "Not Connected" when setting up "Device"

Tags: audio-recording, guitar

Here is what I want to do:

Record what I play on my Guitar which is set up with my computer (Bias FX 2 Amp)

Here is what I have:

Windows 10,
Bias FX 2 Amp,
Reaper 5.34

Here is what I have done so far:

1. Made sure that the **ASIO** plugin is working on my **Bias FX 2**
2. Made sure that **VST** plugin folder is correctly set on **Reaper**

Here is the problem I am having:

As seen in the screenshot I am sharing, Reaper shows "not connected" in the Input and Output sections of Device management in app settings for Reaper.

Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Do you have an interface?

Comment: What ismeant by an interface?

Comment: A device that interfaces a microphone or instruments to your computer, also known as an external sound card. It is telling you that you have none connected so I am led to assume you are not using one

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. No, my audio card is internal and the guitar is connected to the Line in

Comment: I would suggest purchasing some kind of interface because your current set up will not work.

Comment: Can you recommend one or two?

Comment: Not according to the guidelines on this site. But you can just search and find one with an instrument input and choose what price you’re willing to pay.

Comment: So what specific word should I google?

Comment: audio interface, or external audio interface